# How to solve this second-order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, problem-solving

what technique should I use to solve this $v'' e^{v'} -2v=0$ analytically.

Here is what I did:

$v''e^{v'}=2v$ integrate both sides wrt x to get $e^{v'}=v^2 +c$
then I took the natural logarithm to both sides, this gives:

$v'=\ln(v^2 +c)$ integrate again by parts this gives: $v=x \ln(v^2+c) - \int \frac{2v}{v^2 +c} dx = x \ln(v^2+c) - \ln(v^2 +c) + c_1$

Comment: Well what technique have you tried?

Comment: Added it in the original post

Comment: Your first step was a misstep, $e^{v'}$ doesn't equal $v^2 + c$. Differentiate both sides to get $v''e^{v'}$ and $2v v'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shorthand you have
\begin{equation}
v''e^{v'} = 2 v.
\end{equation}
Multiply through by $v'$ to get
\begin{equation}
v''e^{v'}v' = 2 vv'.
\end{equation}
Integrate both sides:
\begin{align*}
\int v'' e^{v'} v' dt &= \int 2 v v' dt \\
\int e^{v'} v' dv' &= \int 2 v dv.
\end{align*}
Use integration by parts to compute the first integral on the left; you can do the final one directly. That’ll get you to a first order equation.